# PHP function behavior after upgrading from 7.0 to 7.2

Tags: php

my functions have become extra strict about passing ALL of the arguments now instead of just what I need)

This used to work

```
function namedFunction($avar, $bvar, $cvar){
.......
}

echo namedFunction('a','b');
```

Now NOTHING works unless I pass

```
echo namedFunction('a','b','');
```

Comment: On your function definition simply set `... $bvar,$cvar = null){...` as a default value. I don't think this is a recent update, but it's been standard for a long time as far as I'm aware....

Comment: You probably have a HUGE error log in PHP 7 with all the WARNINGS that this sort of lax function coding has produced.....

Comment: This was never valid code: https://3v4l.org/kPWVN but it's _extra_ invalid as of 7.1. When you are writing new code you should have `error_reporting` at a level that shows you at _least_ warnings as there is a very good chance that warnings early on will indicate the cause of a later error. Also, 7.2 EOL is coming up, get thee to at least 7.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign a default value to the parameter:

```
function myFunction( $a, $b, $c = "" )
{
  ...
}

myFunction( $a, $b );
```

Check your error logs from when you were doing this with PHP 7.0 - not providing a parameter that has no default value isn't valid syntax in 7.0 or 7.2 (or any other version as far as I remember).